# Assign an attribute to EACH element in my XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to assign an attribute to EACH element I have in my XSD.

Example:

mySchema.xsd

to each of these elements:

```
<xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="benefits" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="best_practices" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="example" type="xs:anyURI"/>
```

I would like that they have this attribute:

```
<xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string"/>
```

In this example, the elements are only 4, but in my case there are many many elements,...any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an attribute then you're essentially changing the *type* of the elements from `xs:string` to your own custom `complexType` that includes the attribute.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/namespace"
           xmlns:tns="http://example.com/namespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:complexType name="labelledString">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

With this type in place you can simply use `type="tns:labelledString"` instead of `type="xs:string"` on your elements, and the same approach would work for the `anyURI` (with another custom type that extends `xs:anyURI`).